# HTML Link to Database Item -- Clojure Web Development

Tags: database, web, hyperlink, clojure, luminus

I am currently writing a website via **Clojure** code that runs on a **Luminus** based framework.
I have a database that stores users and uploaded files (and routes which allow me to do both).
The routes call **SQL** functions that I have written, altering the database.

I **currently** am printing out the list of files like such (in HTML):

```
<ul class="users">
        {% for item in users %}
        <li>
          <p>{{item.file_name}}</p>
          </br> </br>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

I **want** to edit it to have a link to each file as well.
For example, under the `<p>{{item.file_name}</p>` line I could write something like:

```
<a href="home">Home</a>
```

This generates me a link to "/home" for every file_name in the database.
Instead, I would like to create a *link* to each file_name in the database. 
For **example**, if the first listed item was "test.txt" I would want a link to "/test.txt" and so on, through the whole list.

Is this possible to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your template to create the link HTML that is specific to an item.  Something like this:

```
<ul class="users">
  {% for item in users %}
    <li>
      <p><a href="/{{item.file_name}}">{{item.file_name}}</a></p>
      </br> </br>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It's hard to be any more specific than that without more information. You just have to determine how to create a URL for an item. In the code above I used `"/{{item.file_name}}"` based on your examples, but if the URL is more complicated than that, you could add it as a separate key to the `item` and do something like `"{{item.url}}"`.